# The event stops halfway

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am executing an asynchronous anonymous method that is called by an event, but it terminates halfway through without executing half the code.

Method, that called when an event called.

```
private void OnBlockGenerationTime()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);

                if (!ChainMutex.WaitOne(3000))
                    throw new TimeoutException("Cannot access to blockchain, mutex was held too long.");

                var winnerTrx = PoS.GetWinner(Blockchain.LatestBlock.ID);

                ChainMutex.ReleaseMutex();

                if (winnerTrx == null)
                    return;

                var winner = PoolsSet.TransactionPool.GetTxOut(winnerTrx.Trx.Inputs[0]).Address;

                if (winner == CurrentAccount.GetAddress())
                {
                    var (block, reward) = Blockchain.CreateBlock(CurrentAccount.GetPrivateKey()); //here task terminating.

                    CommonLog.Log(LogElementType.OK, $"Our stake won. A new block with ID {block.ID} was created. {reward} AWT were collected.");

                    P2P.BroadcastLatestBlock();
                }
            });
        }
```

Method with infinte task, that calles event:

```
private void RunNewBlockListening()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    while (GetRemainingToNewBlock() != 0) { await Task.Delay(100); }

                    OnNewBlockGeneration?.Invoke();

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            });
        }
```

*I know that asynchronous methods are executed in different ways, but the marked code is never executed when debagged.*

Comment: Most likely, the reason for this behavior is that the async code throws an exception. Please note that you will only "see" this exception if you await the task.

Comment: You could configure the debugger to halt when any exception is thrown. This might be useful here.

Comment: "the marked code" - what do you mean?

Comment: How do you know that only half the code executes? What happens and what do you expect?

Comment: Klaus, in the first code, the line is marked with a comment, starting from that line, the code is not executed

Comment: ok, i try to debug code with halting when any exception is thrown

Comment: after completing the task, I checked the "IsFaulted" field for the returned task, it turned out to be false. If there is no exception in the task, and it still completes execution halfway, then this is something abnormal.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in your method and stepping through the code one line at a time. Maybe `Blockchain.CreateBlock` is hanging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, those who are looking for an answer to catching exceptions in anonymous functions, just click on the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox in the "Exception parameters" tab (Debugging -> Windows -> Exception Parameters).
That's all.